# Adopting Cocoapods in a more complex workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I currently have multiple apps, multiple library projects and am also using several external libraries. I'm rather curious to how I could employ cocoapods in my workflow, and if it would be beneficial.

To give an example, for one of my apps, the workspace I have currently consists of four projects, three of which are library projects:

- MyApp

  - Uses `MyLogicLibrary`, `MyUILibrary` and `MyAdsLibrary`
  - Links with FlurrySDK (an analytics library)
- MyLogicLibrary (contains all kinds of useful tools, for example date formatting and such)
- MyUILibrary (contains all kinds of views and controllers I created)

  - Uses `MyLogicLibrary`
- MyAdsLibrary (contains wrapper classes for Advertisement libs)

  - Uses `MyLogicLibrary` and `MyUILibrary`
  - (Links with AdMobSDK and such)

My question thus are:

- how can I set up cocoapods to work with this structure not using private pods?
- Is it possible to create a pod file for MyApp as well as MyAdsLibrary separately in this case?
- What would the result look like?